# How to add profile fields on Ubercart 3 checkout page?

Tags: 7, users, ubercart

I used to use the uc_profile module to add user profile fields to the D6/Ubercart 2 checkout page, but I cannot find a suitable solution for that same functionality in D7/UC3. Can anyone guide me toward an alternative solution? I need to add things like "birthday" and "shoe size" to the checkout page, and I need those items to be displayed on the users' profiles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the [Extra Fields Checkout Pane](https://drupal.org/project/uc_extra_fields_pane) module.

> This modules allows an administrator to define additional (billing and shipping) address fields (i.e. VAT) as well as custom order fields in Ubercart e-commerce suite. These fields will be available during checkout process and in order handling pages.

Comment: Hello. Link-only answers are not considered good answers on Stack Exchange. Could you at least add a quote from module's page, quoting part that shows it might, indeed, be a solution for OPs needs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Imran. Unfortunately, I don't believe this module meets my requirement of having those fields show up in the user's profile.

Comment: @hockey2112, did you get solution to this problem? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly cannot recall. I want to believe that I did not find a suitable solution, unfortunately.